# finite float numbers being mistaken for nan/inf in scikit-learn IsotonicRegression.score

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

scikit-learn IsotonicRegression class seems to be malfunctioning in its score method.

I am feeding it perfectly fine floating number arrays, the fit method works without raising any exceptions, and then the score method raises the following errors:

```
.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py:445: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
slope = (y_hi - y_lo) / (x_hi - x_lo)[:, None]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "iostonic_error.py", line 20, in <module>
print model.score(x_1d,y_1d)
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 324, in score
return r2_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 2324, in r2_score
y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 65, in _check_reg_targets
y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 283, in check_arrays
_assert_all_finite(array)
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 43, in _assert_all_finite
" or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Here is some minimal example code to recreate this bug:

```
from sklearn.isotonic import IsotonicRegression

x_1d = [ 3.97948718,4.,2.,2.97948718,4.48974359,4.46923077, 2.,3.46923077,4.46923077,4.46923077,3.97948718,3.97948718, 5.46923077,3.,2.48974359]
y_1d = [ 19.,9.,27.,27.,12.,17.,34.,30.,23.,25.,18.,21.,11.,24.,33.]

model = IsotonicRegression(y_min=0, increasing=False, out_of_bounds='clip')

model.fit(x_1d,y_1d)

print model.score(x_1d,y_1d)
```

I have looked in the source code, and found that this error message is coming from sklearn.utils.validations._assert_all_finite
As a test, used the precise code of that function on the input data (both x_1d and y_1d) I was feeding the regression class. it did not raise any exceptions, which leads me to believe somewhere along the way, the score method manipulates the data in a way that corrupts it and introduces either missing or np.inf values.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? I think this problem was recently fixed. Can you check that "model.predict(x_1d)" also gives inf or nan?

Comment: This issue is fixed in the "beta" version of scikit-learn (0.16), but not in 0.15